# Data in Angular Services/Controllers

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript

I usually load data in a service and request this data then in my controllers.

e.g.

```
angular.module "xyz"
  angular.module("myRecipesService", []).service "recipesService", ($http) ->
    self = @
    @.recipes = []
    @.getRecipesFromDatabase = () ->
      return $http.get('/getProovenRecipes').then( (result) ->
        #console.log result.data
        self.recipes = result.data
        return result.data
    @.getRecipes = () ->
      return @.recipes
```

Later I request this data from the service in diff. controller by calling getRecipes.

```
angular.module "xyz"
  .controller 'RecipesCtrl', ($scope, recipesService) ->
    $scope.filteredRecipes = recipesService.getRecipes()
```

Does this store a copy of all recipes in each controller? Or is there a way to directly reference to the data in the service. I remember from my C times, that we used a lot of pointers, which only stored the information where to find the array.

Comment: In this example, I would say storing the data in the service is a code smell, and you should instead only store the data in the controller. If you really want to 'store' the state, you should memoize the call to getRecipesFromDatabase() instead. (again, in this trivial example, with this little info about your problem). Either way, you will pass a *reference* to the original array around (because arrays are 'exotic objects' as defined in the ES6 spec, and all objects in JS are pass-by-reference). You could essentially think of this as a pointer in C.

Comment: The problem is related to another question on Stack Overflow, I just wanted to keep it simple. Former I used a Resolve in a parent state which all my child states could access. Now I needed to remodel, so that one child state does the database query. But I still need to have the same information in all my diff. child states. Thus I used the service, but I'm not sure what is the best way to store the data then, so that all child states (& child controllers) have access to the information, are able to update them etc.

Comment: I felt like fetching it in the controller causes having the same data multiple times. But if everything is just a reference I just need to sync changes and that would be fine.

Comment: if those ui router states rely on state in a parent controller, throw the shared state in the parent controller and expose an API on that controller, then access that controller through `$scope` in the child states. If you want to stick with the state-in-services approach I would strongly recommend you don't put the storing of the state and the data retrieval in the same service (that's two responsibilities)

Answer (score 1):

as `@.recipes` is not a private variable of your service, you could use : `recipesService.recipes` but **this will not WATCH for changes** within if recipesService.recipes changes during your controller life.

Comment: Is there some equivalent like `$scope.$watch` for the vars from the service. At the moment I use boradcasts e.g. `$rootScope.$broadcast('FILTERED')` to signal a change made by one controller.

Comment: no, you have 2 solutions : $scope.$watch in your controller. OR $rootScope.$broadcast (or $emit) in your service + $scope.$on in controller

Comment: So `$scope.$watch` works on the vars in the service. I thought somehow this works only on scope vars, I never really got the use of this. Is this correct: 
`$scope.$watch 'recipesService.recipes', () -> $scope.filteredRecipes = recipesService.recipes`